# TouchableOpacity too slow

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on building an e-commerce app i'm using Expo. the TouchableOpacity is too slow on the entire app i'm giving an example the cart screen i'm not sure why it's acting this way i even tried to switch it to buttons and it's the same latency. Please Note i even tried switching to TouchableWithoutFeedback but it's the same latency
This is my **cartScreen**:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    SafeAreaView,
    Image,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    StatusBar
} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { BottomTabs, Header, HeaderTab, SideBar, Slider, TabNavigation } from '../../components';
import { COLORS } from '../../constants';
import { useStateContext } from '../../context/StateContext';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const CartTab = ( { route, navigation: { goBack } } ) => {
  const {  totalPrice, totalQuantities, cartItems,  setShowCart, toggleCartItemQuanitity, onRemove, incQty, decQty, qty} = useStateContext();
  const navigation = useNavigation();


    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.Header}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => goBack()}
            >
              <Icon icon ='arrow-back-outline' color='#000' size={20}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: '800', fontSize: 20}}>Shopping Cart</Text>
          </View>


          <View style={styles.empty}>
            {cartItems.length < 1 && (
              <View style={{marginTop: 50}}>
              <Icon icon ='cart-outline' color='#000' size={180}/>
              <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16}}>Your Shopping Cart Is empty. Please add a few items</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          </View>

          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.cartBody}>
  {cartItems.length >= 1 && cartItems.map((item, index) => (
    <View key={index}>
      <View style={styles.product}>
          <Image style={styles.CardImages} source={{ uri: `${item.image}` }}/>
          <View style={styles.ProductDetails}>
            <View style={styles.ProductHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.category}>{item.category}</Text>
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onRemove(item)}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                  <Text style={styles.Remove}>Remove</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>                    
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.name.substring(0,30)}</Text>

            <View style={styles.ProductPriceDetails}>
              <Text style={styles.price}>${item.price}</Text>
              <View>
              <View  style={styles.Counter}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', borderRadius: 2, padding: 2}}>
                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => toggleCartItemQuanitity(item.id, 'inc') }>
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                      <Icon icon ='add-outline' color='#0AAD0A' size={20}/>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </View>
                <View>
                  <Text style={{ padding: 0, fontWeight: '800'}}>{item.quantity}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', borderRadius: 2,  padding: 2}}>
                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => toggleCartItemQuanitity(item.id, 'dec') }>
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                      <Icon icon ='remove-outline' color='#DE3634' size={20}/>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </View>
              </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  ))}
</ScrollView>

          <View style={styles.total}>
            {cartItems.length >= 1 && (
              <View style={styles.finalPrice}>
                <View style={styles.OrderInfo}>
                  <Text style={styles.OrderInfoText}>Your Order:</Text>
                  <Text style={{marginTop: 15}}>${parseFloat(totalPrice.toFixed(2))}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.OrderInfo}>
                  <Text style={styles.OrderInfoText}>Other Fees:</Text>
                  <Text style={{marginTop: 15}}>$0</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.5}
                  delayPressIn={0}                 
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('Checkout', {
                      totalPrice: `${totalPrice}`
                    });
                  }}
                >
                <View style={styles.checkoutButton}>

                    <Text style={{textTransform: 'uppercase', color: '#fff', fontWeight: '600'}}>Checkout</Text>

                  <View style={styles.finaltotal}>
                    <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color:'#fff', fontWeight: '600'}}>${parseFloat(totalPrice.toFixed(2))}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            )}
          </View>
        
        </ScrollView>


        {/*<BottomTabs/>*/}
      </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };

  const Icon = (props) => (
    <View>
      <Ionicons 
        name={props.icon} 
        size={props.size} 
        style={{
          marginBottom: 3,
          alignSelf: 'center'
        }} 
        color={props.color}
      />
    </View>
  )
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffff',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
      },


      cartBody: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: 20,
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        flex: 3
      },

      total: {
        width: '98%',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        marginBottom: 20,
        marginTop: 50,
        borderRadius: 6,
        flex: 1,
        bottom: 0

        
      },

      finalPrice: {
        padding: 6,
        
      },

      title: {
        fontSize: 13,
        fontWeight: '600',
        marginBottom: 20
      },

      product: {
        flexDirection: 'row', 
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        width: '95%',
        marginVertical: 5,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.lightGray3,
        borderRadius: 8,
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        padding: 10,
      },

      OrderInfo: {
        flexDirection: 'row', 
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        width: '100%',       
      },

      checkoutButton: {
        marginTop: 50,
        flexDirection: 'row', 
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        borderRadius: 6,
        padding: 20,
        height: 60,
        width: '100%'
      },

      OrderInfoText: {
        fontWeight: '500',
        fontSize: 14,
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        color: '#000',
        paddingTop: 20
      },

      finaltotal:{
        backgroundColor: COLORS.kale,
        padding: 2,
        width: 80,
        height: 40,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 6,
        marginTop: -10
      },

      ProductHeader: {
        flexDirection: 'row', 
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        width: '50%',   
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 10,
        
      },

      category: {
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        color: COLORS.darkGray2,
        fontSize: 13
        
      },

      Remove: {
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        color: COLORS.darkGray2,
        marginLeft: 40,
        fontSize: 13
      
      },

      ProductDetails: {
        marginLeft: 10

      },

      CardImages: {
        width: 80,
        height: 100,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
        borderRadius: 8,
        marginBottom: 10
      },

      Header: {
        marginTop: 40,
        flexDirection: 'row',  
        marginHorizontal: 5, 
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        marginLeft: 20,
        marginRight: 20,
        flex: 0.5   
      },

      ProductPriceDetails: {
        flexDirection: 'row',  
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        width: '67%'
      },

      price: {
        marginTop: 6 
      },

      Counter: {
        flexDirection: 'row',  
        marginHorizontal: 5, 
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        width: 80,
        height: 35,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.lightGray2,
        borderRadius: 3,
        padding: 6,
      },

    });


export default CartTab
```

i'm new to react native so i'm not sure if i have to add or remove something

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: please give me clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your application as a whole gets slow on your actions e.g. the press event on your TouchableOpacity, because they modify the state of your cart products cause the whole parent and subsequently evey item within your list to rerender. A good practice would be to create a component for your product giving it the nececcarry props like amount and name etc. and then memoize that component. This allows a more effective rendering of your whole CartTab component.
That would then look something like this

```
interface ProductProps {
   product: Product;
   qty: number;
 }

const Product: React.FC<ProductProps> = ({ product, qty }) => {
   return (
      <View>
        ... Your product component
      </View>
   );
};

export default memo(Product, productsAreEqual);
```

One important note: If your pass your product like an object, you have to include a function that can compare those objects for equality, since memo by default only does a shallow comparison.

Furthermore, with growing lists like that you could think of utilizing a Flatlist (Or Flashlist for even more optimized rendering), cause then only the components that are actually on screen will get rendered.

Hope that helps.